# How do I configure and access logs in Java and Docker based OpenWhisk actions?

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk

Looking at OpenWhisk [samples](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/tree/master/catalog/samples), it seems like JavaScript-based actions can use `console.log()` to report log information that would be collected and accessible through the activation API.

However, it is not clear how to report logs from Java-based or Docker-based actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logs for OpenWhisk actions are taken from `stdout` and `stderr` of the action. That mechanism applies to all runtimes.

The Docker-based approach assumes that `stdout` of the program you run is the result of the action. Thus it takes `stdout` and tries to JSON-parse it. The result will be the result of the action itself rather than logs. Currently there is no way to write logs in a docker-based action.

Comment: Thanks. Would it make sense to explicitly mention this in the documentation and/or the examples?